# How to use SQL to filter off rows that are in excess (but have not just met) threshold limit?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table like the following:

```
ID|PROMOTION|USER_ID|LIMIT|CUMULATIVE_USAGE|TDATE
01|111111111|AAAAAAA|  2  |       1        |07-21-2020
02|111111111|AAAAAAA|  2  |       3        |07-22-2020
03|111111111|AAAAAAA|  2  |       5        |07-23-2020 <-- remove
04|222222222|AAAAAAA|  4  |       1        |08-21-2020
05|222222222|AAAAAAA|  4  |       3        |08-22-2020
06|222222222|AAAAAAA|  4  |       5        |08-23-2020
07|333333333|AAAAAAA|  5  |       1        |09-21-2020
08|333333333|AAAAAAA|  5  |       3        |09-22-2020
09|333333333|AAAAAAA|  5  |       5        |09-23-2020
```

For each user/promotion id, I want to filter off rows that did not just cross the limit  but had already been in excess of the limit i.e. row where ID=3 in this case.

What SQL logic could I use to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `lag()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lag(cumulative_usage) over (partition by promotion, user_id order by id) as prev_cumulative_usage
      from t
     ) t
where usage <= prev_cumulative_usage or
      prev_cumulative_usage is null;
```